# stream2es: command not found

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'd like to use a script to convert the Enron email dataset first in mbox format, then in a JSON doc. After that the script should automatically import this JSON into elasticsearch using stream2es utility. Here I faced the problem; when I launch the script everything goes well except the `stream2es` utility. In fact, `stream2es: command not found` appears.
I have a folder with the script, the Enron email folder and `stream2es` in it. I grant the permissions to `streams2es`, so I think I have everything to make the script work. 
I'm going to post the script here:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Loading enron data into elasticsearch
#
# Prerequisites: 
# make sure that stream2es utility is present in the path
# install beautifulsoup4 and lxml:
#    sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4
#    sudo easy_install lxml
#
# The mailboxes__jsonify_mbox.py and mailboxes__convert_enron_inbox_to_mbox.py are modified 
# versions of https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web/tree/master/python_code
#
#if [ ! -d enron_mail_20110402 ]; then
#    echo "Downloading enron file"
#   curl -O -L http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/enron_mail_20110402.tgz
#  tar -xzf enron_mail_20110402.tgz
#fi
if [ ! -f enron.mbox.json ]; then
    echo "Converting enron emails to mbox format"
    python mailboxes__convert_enron_inbox_to_mbox.py allen-p > enron.mbox       # allen-p is one of the folders within Enron dataset
    echo "Converting enron emails to json format"
    python mailboxes__jsonify_mbox.py enron.mbox > enron.mbox.json
    rm enron.mbox
fi
echo "Indexing enron emails"
es_host="http://localhost:9200"
curl -XDELETE "$es_host/enron"
curl -XPUT "$es_host/enron" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
        "index.number_of_shards": 5,
        "index.refresh_interval": -1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "email": {
            "properties": {
                "Bcc": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Cc": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Content-Type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Date": {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "format" : "EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"
                },
                "From": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Message-ID": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Mime-Version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Subject": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "To": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-FileName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-Folder": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-From": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-Origin": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-To": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-bcc": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "X-cc": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "bytes": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "offset": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "parts": {
                    "dynamic": "true",
                    "properties": {
                        "content": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "contentType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

stream2es stdin --target $es_host/enron/email < enron.mbox.json
```

Can anyone help me to solve the `stream2es command not found` problem? Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you sure that your `stream2es` has execution rights? What happens if you run `chmod u+x stream2es` and then run your script again?

Comment: I just ran `chmod +x stream2es` as the github guide says. Anyhow if I ran this thing, the script fails reporting `stream2es: command not found`

Comment: @Val Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: Try `./stream2es` instead as your current folder probably isn't in your PATH so `stream2es` cannot be found.

Comment: I put `stream2es` in the `bin` folder and the `stream2es: command not found` disappeared. Now I have other kind of errors which I will try to sum up here:

Comment: I would create a new question since this one is basically solved :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144074/discussion-between-riccardo-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command not found` means that the shell cannot find the `stream2es` command. You have two options:

1. Your script either needs to call `./stream2es` (i.e. call the `stream2es` script located in the same folder) or
2. you need to move `stream2es` in a folder that is located on your `$PATH`